# Prepared default query with result to prepared query with bindings

Tags: php, pdo

I have a query that is working but is does not have binded values:

```
$this->_db->query("SELECT * from posts WHERE post_title LIKE '%$this->search_keywords%' OR post_content LIKE '%$this->search_keywords%' LIMIT 100");
$this->rows_results_found = $this->_db->resultset();

$this->results_found_num = sizeof($this->rows_results_found);
```

I am rewriting it to this one but with no luck:

```
$this->_db->query('SELECT * from posts WHERE post_title LIKE :search_keywords OR post_content LIKE :search_keywords LIMIT 100');
            $this->_db->bind(':search_keywords', '%$this->search_keywords%');

            $this->rows_results_found = $this->_db->resultset();

            $this->results_found_num = sizeof($this->rows_results_found);
```

$this->results_found_num appears always to be an empty array.

This is what I have in the **resultset()** *(It is from another outer class)*:

```
public function resultset() {
        $this->execute();
        return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
```

What I am missing here?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please RTFM how to use prepared statements: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Uhm, just for the record, I wrote the Fk manual. Thank you! :)

Comment: ...then you should be more than qualified to answer your own question...?! :) \*confused\*

Comment: At the very least we're missing a ton of code here, there's not enough information on what the problem is or what exactly is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a valid  connection adjust your function to the following:

```
public function get_posts($conn) {
    $query = 'SELECT * 
              FROM posts 
              WHERE post_title LIKE :search_keywords1 OR 
                    post_content LIKE :search_keywords2 LIMIT 100';
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindValue(':search_keywords1', '%'.$this->search_keywords.'%');
    $stmt->bindValue(':search_keywords2', '%'.$this->search_keywords.'%');
    $stmt->execute();

    return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

Usage:

```
$posts = $this->_db->get_posts($conn);
//var_dump($post)
$this->rows_results_found = count($post);
```

Comment: Thanx a much! I just did not have my query variable and it was not prepared. Now everything is working! I am just using $this->_db-> instead of $stmt-> but I suppose it is the same because my connection is set in another class, that is why I am using _db->. Once again, thanx! :) This was what I needed!